Arduino Interface for 90's Bosch ECU using KW-71 Protocol
I'm currently working on a project where I aim to interface an Arduino with a 90's Bosch Engine Control Unit (ECU) that communicates via the KW-71 Protocol on the K-Line. Additionally, the ECU wake-up procedure utilizes the L-Line.
To set up the interface, I've referred to a circuit shared on m0agx's website https://m0agx.eu/reading-obd2-data-without-elm327-part-2-k-line.html , which was extracted from the ELM327 datasheet. This circuit employs transistors to manage the logic levels between the UART and the K/L Lines.
However, he refers that the UART idle voltage is logically high and that would lead to logical low voltage on the K-Line, so I've added another transistor to invert the signal.
Despite this modification, I'm uncertain about the resistor values I've introduced and whether I should connect the added transistor 12V (V in) or 5V output of the Arduino.
Here's the circuit I'm currently considering:

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding the following:
The appropriateness of the resistor values in the circuit.
Whether it's advisable to the added transistor to the 12V or 5V output of the Arduino.
Any other potential improvements or considerations for this interface setup.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Welcome! What speed does the RX runs on?

Thanks!
The baud rate while communicating is 9600.
The wake up procedure is done at 5 baud.

Then your resistor divider should be fine. If the edges do end up a bit rounded, perhaps lower the R20/R21 divider a bit. Only edge case I could think of for a commercial product intended to be sold would be overvoltage protection. If this is for your own use, I wouldn't bother.

Thanks, what about the part of the circuit in the blue section?

Rating wise, I don’t see any issues, but I can’t say I know the KL-line protocol. My car has it but I only use an off the shelf ELM327 for it.

Thanks a lot, I guess I will try it and see
